# Link git commits with no user to user

Tags: git, github

I have made several commits and pushes until I noticed that my user.email and user.name were not configured.

I would like to know if there is any possibility to associate old commits to my user.

I have repository administration privileges, if necessary.

Best regards,
topastop

Comment: You will have to rewrite history, you can use `git filter-branch` or similar to fix it. This is going to be a headache if you have other people already working based on your commits.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/